# how to download attachments from opportunity in salesforce using rest api

Tags: salesforce, apex

I'm trying to get the attachments that are placed inside a opportunity but I can't doing simple way.

I'm checking the api `services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Opportunity/{id}` but parent_id is not returning or something that relates to attachments. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye6Dr.png)

I would like to know if you have another solution instead of creating a new endpoint
link https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000XnlFQAS,

Comment: Hi Gustavo. Can you explain your use case a bit more? Where is this going to be called from? How do you picture your solution looking?

Comment: Hello, this SF application is integrated with a system that makes quotas for any customer who opens an opportunity in SF and it takes care of the sales part but there is a factor that I need to have access to would be to show a report that is attached within SF.